# Can I change the statefulness of RNN after training?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network, tf.keras

If I build and train my RNN based model with stateful=False, can I simply do (e.g.):

```
model.layers[0].stateful = True
```

And have it take effect as might be expected for use in prediction?  I ask because in other situations (learning rate for example), the exposed parameters are "cosmetic" and don't actually affect behavior.

Comment: @xskxzr Did u test this method? Did you try to fit a model with stateful=False and make predictions then set stateful=True and make predictions? Are the predictions in both cases equal?

Answer (score 1):

If your model is not stateful, model resets the state variable after each batch. You can create a stateful model but manually reset the state variable after each batch in prediction using callbacks (model.reset_states after on_batch_end callback).

Also, why do you want to change statefulness after training ?

Comment: I'm training my model on complete sequences, but in application I will be feeding it one time sample at a time.  I'm a little unclear what statefulness does during training, but I thought it would keep the state between batches, which I don't want.

Comment: Exactly, "stateful=True" allows you to keep the state between batches. Otherwise, it will be reset after each batch. Statefulness is useful if you want your model's state variable to remember long term dependencies.